# Source-Links in Compilation mode not working

Tags: compilation, compilation-mode

I've been experimenting with `M-x compile` recently (I'm using it to start my node.js-project which will output a stack-trace if there is an error.

I get traces like this:

```
Error: Configuration property "loggers" is not defined
    at Config.get (/home/myuser/path/to/project/node_modules/config/lib/config.js:179:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/myuser/path/to/project/lib/setup-logging.js:14:26)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/myuser/path/to/project/index.js:6:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
```

Each of the paths there is actually nicely clickable, however when I do click it (or navigate to it and press `RET`), emacs isn't smart enough to open the right file. Instead, I get a `helm`-popup saying `Find this error in (default setup-logging.js:14): /home/myuser/path/to/project/directory/of/the/currently/open/file` where I then have to navigate to the file myself.

I've looked through the docs but I couldn't find anything relating to this issue, can you guys help me out here?

PS: I'm actually using `projectile-compile-project` rather than `compile` directly, but I get the same results with plain `compile`.

Answer (score 2):

After some tinkering, I was able to trace the problem to emacs wrongly recognizing the column in the trace output as the line number. All I had to do was add a new regexp to `compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist` [like described in this nice post](https://benhollis.net/blog/2015/12/20/nodejs-stack-traces-in-emacs-compilation-mode/) (note that I had to restart emacs for the changes to take effect).